# How can I wake my Canon EOS 1100D up from computer?

Tags: c#, camera, tethering, canon-sdk

I have a **Canon EOS 1100D** camera and control it by my C# program that use it's tethering feature ‎with *Canon EOS Utility dlls*.
I have to shoot one photo every 30 minute all day long, but if I want to send the camera into standby ‎mode between two shots, the camera will be disconnected from my computer and I have to power it ‎on by pressing a key on it.

Is there any way that I can reconnect my camera programmatically?

‎

Note: I'm afraid of keeping the camera ON always.‎

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I guess that it isn't possible because there is no longer a connection between your computer and your camera after switching to standby from which the camera could get any wake up command. Maybe there are some adapters out there that are able to do this but I'm not a camera expert.

Comment: thanks Torben. So i seems I have to keep the camera ON. Can anybody tell me that is it may damage the camera's sensor or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, it turns out that if I lost the connection between the Camera and the Computer, I can do nothing for it. So, I can't turn my Camera ON again.
What I can do is to *keep my Camera always ON* and prevent camera's sleep. (I can do it simply from Camera's setting menu).

And the best thing here is this fact that in **DSLR Cameras** you can keep it ON; even when you don't use it.
In DSLRs, the sutter just opens when shooting command is sent.
in manual use (when user use the camera, not a program or computer), user can see the view from camera's viewfinder eyepiece without using its LCD.

P.S.: Any body can help me to improve this answer? I think I couldn't explain it clearly what I want to say!